# pgfplots: post-processing data created with gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I have managed to use `pgfplots`' `gnuplot` option to solve an implicit equation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
      xmin=8e2,
      xmax=1e8,
      ymin=0.008,
      ymax=0.1
      ]
      \addplot[solid,raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
        set xrange [2300:1e8];
        set yrange [0.008:0.1];
        set logscale xy;
        set samples 100;
        f(R,L) = -2*log10(2.51/(R*sqrt(L))+4e-3/3.71)-1/sqrt(L);
        set cont base;
        set cntrparam levels discrete 0;
        unset surface;
        splot f(x,y)
      };
    \end{loglogaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem here is that gnuplot doesn't sort the result, so that the plot appears closed. How can I sort the data generated by `gnuplot` before it is plotted by `pgfplots`?

I have tried to pass table sorting options to gnuplot:

```
\addplot[...] gnuplot[sort=true,sort cmp={float <}] {...};
```

which didn't work.

My other idea was to call gnuplot from my tex document without plotting immediately. I could then read the data with `pgfplotstable` and process it, but I don't know a convenient way to call gnuplot. My goal is to generate a number of plots in one axis environment only with one call to `pfdlatex`.

---

I noticed that `pgfplots` 1.5.1 does *not* close the plot, but `pgfplots` 1.4.1 does. However, the coordinates are still not sorted and the nodes `current plot end` and `current plot begin` are at the same coordinate (which is bad in my case).

Comment: I don't think this can easily be done, since in general, there's no natural order for the points in a contour plot: They could be (and frequently are) closed polygons, so it's not obvious to which point `(current plot end)` should refer.

Comment: @Jake in general, you are right. In this particular case, sorting may be useful to close the plot.

Comment: Does `pgfplots` interpret contour plots made with gnuplot as contour plots at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two questions if I am not mistaken:

Question 1. How can I sort the result of gnuplot?

Question 2. Why is there a difference between version 1.4 and 1.5 ?

Here are your answers:

Question 1. You can sort the result only using macros from `pgfplotstable`. The `sort` option is only for `\pgfplotstabletypeset`. It works if you allow two passes of pdflatex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \IfFileExists{P.pgf-plot.table}{
        \pgfplotstablesort{\DATA}{P.pgf-plot.table}
    }{}

    \begin{loglogaxis}
    \IfFileExists{P.pgf-plot.table}{
        \addplot[solid,raw gnuplot] table {\DATA};
    }{
        \addplot[solid,raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
            set xrange [2300:1e8];
            set yrange [0.008:0.1];
            set logscale xy;
            set samples 100;
            f(R,L) = -2*log10(2.51/(R*sqrt(L))+4e-3/3.71)-1/sqrt(L);
            set cont base;
            set cntrparam levels discrete 0;
            unset surface;
            splot f(x,y)
        };
    }
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The key idea is to use `\IfFileExists` to distinguish between first and second run - and to use `\pgfplotstablesort` to load the sorted table into `\DATA`. Plotting it does what you wanted.

ATTENTION: I used `P.tex` as my main tex file name. You need to adjust it.

Note that the experiment revealed a small bug in pgfplots: moving the `\pgfplotstablesort` macro into the axis fails. I will fix that (there is a callback which should not be active).

A suitable modification would be to write a temporary file containing the gnuplot script and run gnuplot manually using `\write18{gnuplot datafilename}`.

Question 2. Starting with version 1.5, pgfplots will close gaps in plots -- unless one uses `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}` or newer, in which case it will not close them.

The new feature allows to add empty lines into a data files in order to define piecewise functions (i.e. pgfplots will generate a gap at empty lines).

The use of `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` will restore the old handling and close the gap.

Comment: Using `\write18` to call gnuplot was a good idea! I now use `\write` to store my gnuplot options (like it is done by `pgfplots`), `\write18` to call gnuplot and post-processing tools, and then plot the result with `\addplot table`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial solution derived from the answer by Christian. The major drawback is that the data cannot be sorted (and therefore generated) in the `loglogaxis` environment, because `pgfplotstablesave` is not known there.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gnuplotOptions}[2][pgf-plot]{%
  \newwrite\tempfile%
  \immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.#1.gnuplot% 
  \immediate\write\tempfile{set table "\jobname.#1.table";}% 
  \immediate\write\tempfile{set format "\@percentchar.7e";}%
  \immediate\write\tempfile{#2}%
  \immediate\closeout\tempfile%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\gnuplot}[1][pgf-plot]{%
  \immediate\write18{gnuplot \jobname.#1.gnuplot}% 
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \gnuplotOptions{%
        set xrange [2300:1e8];
        set yrange [0.008:0.1];
        set logscale xy;
        set samples 100;
        f(R,L) = -2*log10(2.51/(R*sqrt(L))+4e-3/3.71)-1/sqrt(L);
        set cont base;
        set cntrparam levels discrete 0;
        unset surface;
        splot f(x,y);
      }
      \gnuplot{}
    \pgfplotstablesave[sort=true,sort cmp={float <}]{\jobname.pgf-plot.table}{\jobname.pgf-plot.sorted.table}
    \begin{loglogaxis}
      % cannot create and sort the table here because pgfplotstablesave is unknown in the axis environment (pgfplots 1.5)
      \addplot[raw gnuplot] table[x index=0, y index=1] {\jobname.pgf-plot.sorted.table};
    \end{loglogaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `gnuplotOptions` command accepts one optional argument which behaves like `pgfplots`'s `id` key. All options are written to an option file for gnuplot. This key can also be passed to gnuplot by using `\gnuplot[someid]{}` to make gnuplot find the right option file.

`\pgfplotstablesave` creates a copy of the table generated with gnuplot and writed the sorted table back to a new file.

The result is plotted as usual with `\addplot table`.