# connecting nearest points

Tags: pgfplots, points

I'm fairly new to pgfplots and latex and strugling a bit with connecting points in pgfplots.

I have a bunch of points and want pgfplots to connect each point to the point next to them. To get a line around all points. Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass {article}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    xmin=0,
    title={test},
    grid=major, 
    width=10cm,
    ]
    \addplot table [
        col sep=semicolon,
        mark=+
        ] 
        {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But instead of connecting each point to the next one it does something like this:
[image]

Is there anyone how can help me?

Comment: Looks like a sequence error in the file `data.dat` but without this file it is hard to tell.

Comment: It seems to be due to the sorting of your points. As far as I know pgfplots plots the points line by line so you need to apply a sorting method prior to plotting. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64014/how-to-sort-table-for-plotting-with-pgfplots) might help

Comment: This is an interesting question, but without the data in `data.dat` we can't really reproduce this easily and so it will be difficult to help you if we have to make up data points before we can even investigate what is going on.