# How to draw graphs

Tags: graphics

Maybe this question should not be here, but for me it seems the only way to get the answer! 
My questions are:

- Which program a mathematician can use to write a paper in mathematics which contains a lot of geometrical graphs?
- How they drew the pictures in the books?
- Is it just hand drawing and then paste in a proper place in the paper? Or the only way is to be very professional in LaTeX?
- Is there any computer program converts a hand-draw picture into a digital code?

Comment: Slightly related: [Why draw diagrams using LaTeX when there are open source tools like OpenOffice?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102590/13304)

Comment: I would recommend splitting up your question as it only concerns LaTeX a little bit and is more about current practices in (mathematical) publishing. There are at least a hundred different plotting/graphing software packages out there that mathematicians currently use. Hardly anything today is hand drawn/digitized. LaTeX is important for the typesetting, it can incorporate different image formats as graphs.

Comment: I may be wrong, A possible duplicate of [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205) and [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972/15717) With Claudio's link.

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to draw diagrams with computers.

- If you like drawing with click and drag or with drawing pad, then you have to use:

  - Inkscape,
  - Illustrator (commercial),
  - Freehand (commercial),
  - SolidWorks (commercial),
  - AutoCad (commercial),
  - 3D Studio Max (commercial),
  - GeoGebra,
  - etc.
- If you prefer scripting then you can use:

  - PSTricks ([supports 3D drawing much better than TikZ](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery3D/Gallery3D) and even [projection](http://pstricks.blogspot.com/)),
  - TikZ,
  - Metapost,
  - Aymptote,
  - XYPic,
  - Octave,
  - Maxima,
  - Mathematica (commercial),
  - Matlab (commercial),
  - Mathcad (commercial),
  - etc.

Hand-drawn diagrams can be converted to digital ones by

- scanning them to get rastered images
- vectorizing the rastered images to get vector graphics.

Using a search engine you can find many "raster to vector" converters.

Comment: Why no `pgfplots`?

Comment: @HarishKumar: I thought it belongs to TikZ's world so I did not need to mention it explicitly.

Comment: @percusse: Fortunately, Octave is free!

Comment: @Dror Well I wouldn't call it fortunately but indeed I missed it :)

Comment: @percusse: But where is your previous comment? :-)

Comment: It's not needed anymore

Comment: @Karl'sstudents Do you mean [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) by Inkspace?

Comment: @hpesoj626: Thanks for informing the changed name. :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you have some background with the terminal/command line, then I would suggest the following tools.

Perhaps an overkill for many people, but how about `python` with [`numpy/scipy`](http://www.scipy.org/). And how about [`sage`](http://www.sagemath.org/) which is also built on top of `python`?

[`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is also a powerful free and open source graphing utility that can be used as a standalone application or with LaTeX packages [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) and [`tkz-fct`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-fct). You can search this site for examples. For instance, the post: [pgfplots: post-processing data created with gnuplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43885/pgfplots-post-processing-data-created-with-gnuplot)

[`R`](http://www.r-project.org/) is a free and open source statistical software that is also widely used. It even has `Sweave` and `knit-r` packages just for running `R` commands in a TeX document. There have also been several examples in this site about these packages.

When I was using Windows, I remember also to have used [`winplot`](http://math.exeter.edu/rparris/winplot.html) for simple graphs.

Most standalone graphics software has the ability to export into picture files. These can then be included in your LaTeX document with the `\includegraphics` command. For LaTeX graphing packages like `pgfplots` which is built on top of `tikz` on the other hand, you can write the code directly into your `.tex` document.

### Update

I forgot to mention [`Scilab`](http://www.scilab.org/), which is also a free alternative to Matlab.

If you are looking for something to draw graphs in Graph Theory, you might want to look at [`tkz-berge`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge) which is also built on top of `tikz`. Here is an example from the manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz,convert,border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape = circle,
                shading = ball,
                ball color = green,
                minimum size = 24pt,
                draw},
         EdgeStyle/.style = {thick,
                double = orange,
                double distance = 1pt,
                }}
\SetVertexLabel\SetVertexMath
\grCrown[RA=3,RS=6]{4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From OP's previous Q, he might be looking at `algebraic topology graphs` related to [graph theory](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-graph). although i am not a pure math expert.

Comment: @texenthusiast Perhaps. Anyway, I included an example.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `TikZ`/`PGF` package. You can find plenty of examples at [www.texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), and the package manual can be found [here](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), and contains a very comprehensive introduction.

There is also the `pstricks` package. But personally I like `TikZ` better because you can directly compile the code with `pdflatex`.

I'm not aware of any program that can digitize hand-drawn pictures. Even if there is, like the ones that convert hand-written equations to `LaTeX` codes, I suspect that its output cannot have the same quality as those produced by a plotting program.

Comment: You should try `potrace` (command-line) or `Incscape` to convert raster graphics to vector format.
The result clearly depends on the image, but it could be very impressive.

Comment: @g.kov: Really? I'll definitely check it out